# Prevent access to derived classes except via factory

Tags: c#

I have an abstract class which has a static factory method for returning its sub-classes:

```
public abstract class ITop {
    public static ITop MakeMeOne(whatever x) {
        if(x == something) {
            return BottomA(x);
        }
        else {
            return BottomB(x);
        }
    }
}

public class BottomA : ITop {
    public BottomA(whatever x) {}
}

public class BottomB : ITop {
    public BottomB(whatever x) {}
}
```

I would like to hide the implementations of `BottomA` and `BottomB` from the rest of the world (including unrelated classes in the same assembly). so they are only accessed through `ITop`.  This seems simple, but I haven't been able to find the correct combination of accessors to do it.

**EDIT:**

Various people have pointed out that I can make everything internal, but hiding from classes within the same assembly is a key requirement, so that doesn't solve it.

Comment: Change your `public class A` to `internal`.

Comment: Also: make the constructor internal, or make the entire class private to the factory class. Here is an example of the latter: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Samples-for-Parallel-b4b76364/sourcecode?fileId=44488&pathId=1696822056

Comment: Internal won't hide it from other classes in the same assembly though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like something a private inner class will solve.

```
public abstract class ITop {
    public static ITop MakeMeOne(whatever x) {
        if(x == something) {
            return BottomA(x);
        }
        else {
            return BottomB(x);
        }
    }

    private class BottomA : ITop {
        public BottomA(whatever x) {}
    }

    private class BottomB : ITop {
        public BottomB(whatever x) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Can even define `ITop` as partial and move `BottomA` or `BottomB` into their own separate files too.

Answer (score 2):

I would define an interface for `ITop` and make 'bottom' other classes internal. If you want them to be 'invisible' to other types in the same assembly, define them as private nested classes inside `ITop`.

```
public interface ITop
{
}

public abstract class Top : ITop {
    public static ITop MakeMeOne(whatever x) {
        if(x == something) {
            return BottomA(x);
        }
        else {
            return BottomB(x);
        }
    }

    private class BottomA : Top {
        public BottomA(whatever x) {}
    }

    private class BottomB : Top {
        public BottomB(whatever x) {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can make the constructor internal, so only the factory class can invoke it.
2. You can make the entire class private to the factory class. Here is an example of the latter: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Samples-for-Parallel-b4b76364/sourcecode?fileId=44488&pathId=1696822056.

What you choose to do, depends on exactly what you wish to make vfisibel and what you wish to hide.

Comment: I want the entire implementation of the derived classes to be hidden, so that the only access is via the public methods of ITop.